# Admin LTE layout fails to apply in Angular JS with ui-router

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, adminlte

I'm using Admin LTE theme and Angular JS with ui-router. The problem is that the layout fails to load using Angular JS with ui-router on view. There is an existing issue in here

[AdminLTE and AngularJS content wrapper wrong min-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556569/adminlte-and-angularjs-content-wrapper-wrong-min-height)

but I can't seem to understand on how to fix this. I've researched on github repo of this theme and the author suggest to apply $.AdminLTE.layout.fix() on every views which I don't know how. I've put this code in my controller but I'm getting the error "$.AdminLTE is undefined". Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

index.html should be something like this

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-collapse sidebar-mini fixed">
    <!-- the app goes here -->
    <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="ApplicationCtrl" ui-view>
    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->
</body>
```

layout.html should be something like this

```html
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row" ui-view> </div>
    </section>
</div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

You need to configure route map some thing like this

```js
angular.module('myApp', [ 
    'ui.router'    
]).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('layout', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'layout.html'            
        })
        .state('layout.main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```